# Remove data grid view based on data

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

Can I actually remove data grid view based on data? For example, there is a column header named food, and in this 'food' columns there are many 'breed' in it. So, what I want to do is, I want to delete all of the rows that include this breed.

Here's the example for a code :

```
tbl_recipeheader.Rows.Add(btn);
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = 1;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = 1;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value = Breed;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value = This Is Description;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value = 100;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[6].Value = DateTime.Now;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[7].Value = Employee 1;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[1].Cells[8].Value = A;

tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = 2;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value = 2;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = Breed;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[4].Value = This Is Description 2;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[5].Value = 200;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[6].Value = DateTime.Now;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[7].Value = Employee 2;
            tbl_recipeheader.Rows[2].Cells[8].Value = A;
```

In there, everything is different except for the breed. So, I want to delete that both rows, because the foodname is same.

Comment: Can you post some sample code. This can be done but it's hard to give an answer without something to off of. According to community guidelines your post should include Example, Sample, and then one of us will post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter like below:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = testGridView.DataSource;
        bindingSource.Filter = testGridView.Columns[“Food”].HeaderText.ToString() + " NOT LIKE '%" + someBreed + "%'";
        testGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```